# catching signals in different threads in gtest

Tags: c++, multithreading, unit-testing, googletest

I'm having a multi-threaded application and I want to test the behaviour of sending specific signals to these threads (ie. to verify that the EINTR-errors are occuring on blocking functions).

In the thread I set something like:

```
 struct sigaction sa {}; 
 sa.sa_handler = func;
 sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);

 sa.sa_flags = SA_NODEFER; 
 sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, [](int){std::cout << "SIGUSR1 called\n";});
```

Now, If I send a signal from gtest via:

```
TEST(Thread, ThreadSignals) {

  Thread test_thread;
  std::future<int> future = std::async(&Thread::test, &test_thread);
  ASSERT_NE(test_thread.get_id(), 0); // get_id() returns the id of the test_thread
  ASSERT_NE(test_thread.get_id(), pthread_self()); 
  pthread_kill(test_thread.get_id(), SIGUSR1); 
}
```

gtests ends with the signal message like:

```
[ RUN      ] Thread.ThreadSignals
User defined signal 1
```

, and not with the expected behavior (eg. printing the msg). Out of gtest I have no problem with task.

Also, fetching the signal in the TEST-case didn't prevent gtest from exiting.
I found settings, like

```
// debugging information when fatal signals are raised.
GTEST_DECLARE_bool_(install_failure_signal_handler);
```

, but they didn't change anything - or I don't know, where to set them...

(I'm currently switching from catch2 because I had hope that I can test signals here)

Thx for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle this works.
I did not set the sa_handler correctly!